# Nesting select menus inside div breaks jQuery menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a multi chained dropdown system using jQuery.

My demo here works great: https://jsfiddle.net/m27pnyo3/

**However**, when I want to nest each select menu in a `<div>` element, I am having problems. I believe these problems stem from my use of `$(this).parent())`.

See [this revised Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cysnw6w5/) with `<div>` elements around each `<select>` - you can see it breaks :(

Can someone explain what I change in my jQuery below to resolve this?

```
$(function() {    

    $(".series").each(function() {
        $(this).chained($(".mark", $(this).parent()));
    });
    $(".model").each(function() {
        $(this).chained($(".series", $(this).parent()));
    });
    $(".engine").each(function() {
        $(this).chained([
            $(".series", $(this).parent()),
            $(".model", $(this).parent())
        ]);
    });

});
```

Comment: Its breaking because the this parent now is the div that surround the select control

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know how I resolve this? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another .parent()

```
this.parent().parent()
```

Now you have added a div as parent and this should get it to original destination.

Comment: That is depressingly simple. Must remember that one in the future. Many thanks @Agney :-D

Comment: `this.parent()` seems to be chaining jQuery methods `.parent()` to a DOM node, this is likely to generate an error (assuming that I'm not misunderstanding what `this` is, in context).

Comment: Happy to Help @michaelmcgurk

Answer (score 1):

If you change you javascript it works:

```
$(function() {    

    $(".series").each(function() {
        $(this).chained($(".mark", $(this).parent().parent()));
    });
    $(".model").each(function() {
        $(this).chained($(".series", $(this).parent().parent()));
    });
    $(".engine").each(function() {
        $(this).chained([
            $(".series", $(this).parent().parent()),
            $(".model", $(this).parent().parent())
        ]);
    });

});
```